# On 16.04, ifconfig-style interface-alias is lost when dhclient fails to get a lease

Tags: 16.04, networking, interface, ifconfig, dhclient

I have a lot of machines (both old ubuntu14.04 as well as newer ubuntu16.04) that have their integrated ethernet configured like this:

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
metric 5
# Also have a fixed IP for infrastructure-less connections.
# Don't add a gateway, it would become a default-gw
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 192.168.200.10
metric 10
mtu 8192
```

Normally, this works great and I get the following interfaces when doing ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 94:c6:91:18:69:20  
          inet addr:192.168.2.11  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          ...

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 94:c6:91:18:69:20  
          inet addr:192.168.200.10  Bcast:192.168.200.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          ...
```

That means I can either get an address through DHCP, and, at the same time, have a static address that I can use when connecting the machine directly to another machine.

However, I recently noticed that when I start the machine up without a DHCP server on the network (i.e., machine-to-machine only), dhclient tries to get an address for 300 seconds and then gives up. In that moment, my eth0:1 is deleted and thus, the box becomes inaccessible via network.

This wasn't always the case, and I wonder

- why is this happening?
- what changed?

What I have tried:

- I read dhclient.conf and saw that dhclient keeps a list of previosuly-successful leases in `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases`. When I delete this file, the problem no longer appears
- I have looked at dhclient-script, and while I'm not sure that its actually used in the process, it contains a lot of suspicious code like `ip -4 addr flush dev ...`.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

So I found out:

When dhclient times out on eth0, it checks /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.lease for a recorded lease that is still valid (i.e., "expire" is in the future). If it finds such a lease, it runs dhclient-script (and puts reason=TIMEOUT and the lease's settings in the env.)

The relevant section of dhclient-script is

```
TIMEOUT)
    if [ -n "$alias_ip_address" ]; then
        # flush alias IP
        ip -4 addr flush dev ${interface} label ${interface}:0
    fi

    # set IP from recorded lease
    ip -4 addr add ${new_ip_address}${new_subnet_mask:+/$new_subnet_mask} \
        ${new_broadcast_address:+broadcast $new_broadcast_address} \
        dev ${interface} label ${interface}

    if [ -n "$new_interface_mtu" ]; then
        # set MTU
        ip link set dev ${interface} mtu ${new_interface_mtu}
    fi

    # if there is no router recorded in the lease or the 1st router answers pings
    if [ -z "$new_routers" ] || ping -q -c 1 "${new_routers%% *}"; then
        # if we have $new_rfc3442_classless_static_routes then we have to
        # ignore $new_routers entirely
        if [ ! "$new_rfc3442_classless_static_routes" ]; then
                if [ -n "$alias_ip_address" ] &&
                   [ "$new_ip_address" != "$alias_ip_address" ]; then
                    # separate alias IP given => set up the alias IP & add host route to it
                    ip -4 addr add ${alias_ip_address}${alias_subnet_mask:+/$alias_subnet_mask} \
                        dev ${interface} label ${interface}:0
                    ip -4 route add ${alias_ip_address} dev ${interface} >/dev/null 2>&1
                fi

                # set if_metric if IF_METRIC is set or there's more than one router
                if_metric="$IF_METRIC"
                if [ "${new_routers%% *}" != "${new_routers}" ]; then
                    if_metric=${if_metric:-1}
                fi

                # set default route
                for router in $new_routers; do
                    ip -4 route add default via ${router} dev ${interface} \
                        ${if_metric:+metric $if_metric} >/dev/null 2>&1

                    if [ -n "$if_metric" ]; then
                        if_metric=$((if_metric+1))
                    fi
                done
        fi

        # update /etc/resolv.conf
        make_resolv_conf
    else
        # flush all IPs from interface
        ip -4 addr flush dev ${interface}
        exit_with_hooks 2
    fi
```

So it first tries to ping the router in the lease and fails, then advances to "# flush all IPs from interface" and calls "ip -4 addr flush dev eth0", which also tears down eth0:1.

The second question, what changed: we are using a new DHCP server with much longer lease-times. Previously they were set to about an hour, so one hour after the last connection to the LAN this problem wouldn't show (dhclient cannot find a valid recorded lease), whereas now it was 12h.